# best way to cleanly display 15-20 youtube videos in a webpage?

Tags: jquery, youtube

I am currently building a website for a client who has about 20 or so videos that he wants put on a video gallery page and I was wondering if you guys could help me out and give me some advice on how to go about this.

I have found yoxview, possibly lightbox... but I don't know if that popup window is really good for video browsing.

Also, should/could this be asked in the webmasters instead of stackoverflow?

Comment: Yep, I think webmasters would be a better place to ask this, however, I would probably go with a popup or something myself. I do kind-of like Jason's suggestion, but I can't possibly think of what else to put on that page besides the video. It would look slightly dull, ihmo.

Comment: @with a dot ... I have a site that does just this.  On the page with the video we include some pull quotes from the video. It's not live yet, so I cannot show... but it looks good. ;-)

Comment: my bad, I'll remember that in the future. It won't be just video, I was hoping to have a small description of the video with each video and maybe a general content area right above it... so I am not worried about that.

Answer (score 2):

With that many videos, I would create images on the page for each video and then have the image linked to another page on the site with the video.

Comment: Okay, I have thought of that, seems like more work for me haha.

Comment: @Phil.  A bit more work.  But better for downloading for the user.

Answer (score 2):

[Something I created](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/7twWb/) long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a few web pages with video capabilities and there are plenty of jquery viewers that would work nicely.  I would say that you need to decide how you are going to deliver the videos, flash vs html5, and then go from there.  If you are unsure of what you want, I would start with videojs because it has fallback support if the client browser does not have HTML5.

Next you have to figure out how you want to display the videos: grid fashion, list, slider...  Once you have this, you just need to tie in the video viewer.  I personally like the lightbox style with a pop up and modaling the rest of the page.  You could even do a related videos under the playing video inside the lightbox pop up and when they click the new video, just have it refresh the jquery player.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [AnythingSlider](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/video.html). It has an extension that can pause videos that aren't in view and *continue* playing videos when they come back into view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mixture of [JqueryUI Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and [Ajax calls](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Have it so when the user clicks on an image of the video in question, call an ajax function that posts the id of the youtube video to an external page.

That page then fills in the id in the needed places in the embed code, and then spits it back out.

You then take that code and put it into the dialog box, and then open in.

I haven't tried it myself, but that would be the route I would take.

Hope this helps!